# Which Slack app scopes should be used to manage channel like Sentry or JIRA?

Tags: oauth, slack, slack-api, scopes

I've read a lot about scopes for Slack OAuth flow here:

- https://api.slack.com/methods
- https://api.slack.com/scopes
- https://api.slack.com/legacy/oauth-scopes

Some methods are deprecated, some should work, for others - no good documentation or examples.
But still don't know which scopes should I use for my app if I want:

- do auth flow for user;
- create own channel for integration (like Sentry, JIRA, GitHub and others do);
- push messages to that channel.

After all these documentation I can't find complete list of what I need and be sure that it will work.

**Questions:**

- which scopes should I use?
- can I set them like `admin,channels,bot` or be more specific `channels:join,channels:manage,...`

**Examples:**

- I used `channels:write,conversations` but got following error:

```
Invalid permissions requested
Invalid scope: channels:write,conversations
```

- I used `channels:manage` but it's asking about existing channels only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use: `channels:read,groups:read,channels:manage,chat:write` from [this tutorial](https://api.slack.com/tutorials/understanding-oauth-scopes-bot).

In response you'll get following:
`chat:write,im:write,channels:read,channels:history,pins:read,reactions:read,users:read,channels:manage,incoming-webhook,groups:read`

Not sure if they are enough for you, but looks like should work.